# More than one root ViewGroup per app page?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

When you are creating different layouts for an app, is it possible to have more than one parent layout on the same page?

For example, place LinearLayout and RelativelyLayout on the same page of an app. Either putting one layout inside the other, or seperate on the same page.

Or, can you only have one root ViewGroup per app page?

Comment: How exactly do you mean "more than one parent layout on the same page"? Are you wanting to have a `LinearLayout` and a `RelativeLayout` side by side?

Comment: Their will be only one ViewGroup (FramLayout) per process/app.
Even if you have more than one acitivty their will be one viewgroup which will render your activity view.
Yes can have viewgroup per app page but it will render in main viewgroup called framlayout.
LinearLayout, RelativeLayout are derived from viewgroup so indirectly each app page has their own viewgroup.

Comment: @Mike M.  Inside the main Parent View, can I have more than one View Groups?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Ultimately, everything's inside one content `ViewGroup` within the `Activity`, but you can have as many "sibling" `ViewGroup`s within that as you want. A layout file, though, can have only one root `ViewGroup`, if that's really what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can have unlimited number of `View`, `ViewGroup`, `ViewParent` classtype instances in your root `View`, as you said, either placing one layout inside the other, or seperated on the same page.

Btw the `View` cannot have more than 1 `View` as its direct parent.

Comment: Thank you. I just started this week and was hoping you could do this.